# Is it possible to point a subdomain at a droplet, without having to move domain to digitalocean?

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a domain, example.com, and I want to point a subdomain, test.example.com, at one of my droplets, WITHOUT having to move the domain to digital oceans nameservers. is this possible and how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, it's very much possible. Go to your DNS manager, and create an A record for your subdomain pointing to your DigitalOcean droplet's public IP.

For example, to point your subdomain `test` to your droplet with IP `13.13.13.13`, set the following A record.

```
Type   Name   IPv4 Address
----   ----   ------------
A      test   13.13.13.13
```

Comment: @DeltaFlyer No, it would be the DNS manager at the site where the domain and subdomain are owned; Eg: godaddy, namecheap, etc.